# MD5 password hashing in Linq Query

Tags: linq, hash, linq-to-sql, md5

i have the following Linq query:

```
 bool exists = db.Users.Any(i => string.Compare(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(i.password, i.username))).ToString(), toCheck) == 0);
```

I have the following error:

```
Method &#39;Byte[] GetBytes(System.String)&#39; has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Comment: There are so many things in that query that you can't do with Entity Framework or Linq-to-Sql that it isn't even funny :-)

Comment: ok.. then can you point a way do it properly?

Comment: Depends on what you are really trying to do... There are at least two "morally wrong" things in what you wrote... You are using `Encoding.ASCII` for a username and a password (instead of for example using UTF8), you are saving a password in cleartext on the db (`i.Password`)

Comment: It is md5 for password.

Comment: And on the point of the correctness of the code... `ComputeHash` returns a `byte[]`. You can't simply `ToString()` it. And it seems strange that you have on the DB the cleartext version of the username and password while on the PC you only have the hashed version of the username+password.

Comment: Plus all the problems with using that you can't `md5.ComputeHash` on the DB.

Comment: on db i have clear username and md5 password. The code is from a method which receives a string - md5(md5(username) + md5(password)) as an authentication string and returns if that user exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107121/discussion-between-bogdan-constantin-and-xanatos).

Comment: There are only two solutions that I consider to be "acceptable": you save on the DB the md5 hash together with username and password OR you pass the username along with the md5 to your function, then you do `.Where(x => x.username == yourusername)` and on the returned users you calculate outside the query the MD5.

Comment: WHY would you ever want to calculate a weak and insecure password hash? Why store a clear-text password in the database anyway? The *proper* way to authenticate passwords is a) use .NET's built in mechanisms with at least SHA-256 or b) use one of the *cryptographic* hashing functions that use salting and a few thousand hashing iterations, and store only the hash in the database. MD5 hashes can be cracked in minutes nowadays

Comment: @xanatos hashing an unsalted password with MD5 can never be considered acceptable. Cracking it with a lookup table is probably faster than *calculating* it by now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He is saving the password in clear text. This isnt "acceptable" by definition. In the "unacceptability" of this pre-condition, saving a non-salted MD5 of the password together with the password is "acceptable". This is the reason I haven't posted a reply to this question: I consider the precondition to be *completely* unacceptable.

Comment: Solved everything. I`m just passing the authString now so no password/username parsed in clear. I`ll come back with the full solution when everything is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "[AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" extension method will force the contents of the "Users" table to be returned to your application, where the remainder of the expression is evaluated. This avoids the need to only use .net functions that are also supported in SQL server.

```
 bool exists = 
    db
    .Users
    .Select(
        user =>
            new
            {
                user.password,
                user.username
            })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Any(i => string.Compare(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(i.password, i.username))).ToString(), toCheck) == 0);
```